# MySQL combine data from multiple rows into one row of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, grouping

I have data that looks like this example for 1 user - I only have 1 table:

```
ID     procedure  date
12345     2        2023-02-27
12345     3        2023-02-06
12345     4        2023-02-13
12345     5        2023-02-27
12345     8        2023-02-27
```

I need it to be in 1 row as, with data in separate columns
:

```
12345 2 2023-02-27 3 2023-02-06 4 2023-02-13 5 2023-02-27 8 2023-02-27
```

The codes 2,3,4,5, & 8 will be replaced by text probably using a case statement.

I've tried grouping, joining, concatenating but nothing is giving me the desired result.

Using a case statement approach is the closest I've gotten but it gave the date from the first row for all date columns and only gave the the procedure correctly in 2 of the columns, the others it gave me a null.

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(date SEPARATOR ' ')`

Comment: These need to be in separate columns.  I neglected to state that specifically.

Comment: Then what you want is a "pivot". I've provided a link to that.

Comment: I looked at those, the case statements I mentioned earlier that got me closest are much like that but the wrong date comes in.  Here is how I have it currently - why don't the correct dates come along with the procedure code:    
 select 
donor_code
,case procedure_id
 when 1 then 'WB'
End ProcedureCodeWB
,date as EligibilityDateWB

,case procedure_id    
 when 3 then 'APH'
End ProcedureCodePLT
,date as EligibilityDatePLT

,case procedure_id    
 when 2 then 'DRBC'
End ProcedureCodeDRBC
,date as EligibilityDateDRBC 

etc.
from .....

Comment: Please post your query in the question.

Comment: You need an aggregation function, like shown in the linked question: `SELECT MAX(CASE ...)`

Comment: Here is some of the query - the entire doesn't fit.  Also I don't see a linked question for select Max(case) but I can search for it.

select 
donor_code 
,if(procedure_id = 1,'WB',null) as  ProcedureCodeWB
,if(procedure_id = 1,date,null) as EligibilityDateWB

,if(procedure_id = 3,'APH',null) as ProcedureCodePLT
,if(procedure_id = 3,date,null) as EligibilityDatePLT

...more here but just different id numbers and aliases...

from rrv.donor_eligibility
inner join rrv.vw_donor_becs on becs_id = id
where date > '2023-02-01'
and becs_id = 20815

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit it into the question with code formatting.

Comment: You still have no aggregation function. `MAX(CASE WHEN procedure_code = 1 THEN date END) AS date1, MAX(CASE WHEN procedure_code = 2 THEN date END) AS date2, ...`

Comment: I found and tried Max(case) and it is working. Thank you